# TS2453 Using componentFactoryResolver

Tags: angular

I have the issue with the componentFactoryResolver.

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.getItemMap(this.film.type));

getItemMap (type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'comedy':
            return ComedyFilmComponent;
        case 'horror':
            return HorrorFilmComponent;
    }
}
```

On the compilation it throws me the next error:

```
ERROR in ...(45,34): The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly. Type argument candidate 'ComedyFilmComponent' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'CartoonFilmComponent'.
Property 'isShownDetails' is missing in type 'HorrorFilmComponent'.
```

How can i fix it, and what is the matter?

ComedyFilmConponent:

```
Component({
  selector: 'comedy-film',
  templateUrl: './comedy-film.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comedy-film.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
});
export class ComedyFilmComponent implements OnInit {
    private isShownDetails;

    constructor(@Host() private parent: MainComponent) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isShownDetails = false;
    }
}
```

HorrorFilmComponent is the same. There is no logic there.

Comment: need more  code, where is (45:34) ?

Comment: @Maximus, it is this line 
`componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.getItemMap(this.film.type));`

Comment: yeah, but as I said, we need to see more code, what does `this.g‌​etItemMap(this.film.‌​type` return?

Comment: @Maximus, i added to the description source code of getItemMap function

Comment: how is 1ComedyFilmComponent1 implemened? what is `CartoonFilmComponent`?

Comment: @Maximus update the description. Maybe it will help.